# Проблема в подключении chromedriver в Intellij IDEA maven Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, maven, юнит-тесты

Ошибка:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
```

Первый раз пробую использовать тесты и Selenium для действий на сайте.

Написал следующий код:

```
package GMail;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestGMail {

    @Test

    public void firstTest() throws InterruptedException {
        // устанавливаем переменную webdriver в system property
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\IGor\\Desktop\\ProjectMaven\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe"); // название и путь

        //Инициализируем веб-драйвер для тестов в Google Chrome
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // команда для открытия страницы
        driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
    }

}
```

Выдается ошибка:

```
[![Ошибка в IDEA][1]][1]
```

В maven прописано следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SheetAndJava</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
            <version>v4-rev493-1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-jackson2</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> <!--  Excel-->
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  JUnit-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  Selenium Java-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 1):

У вас получается конфликт зависимости `Google Guava`. Попробуйте исключить одну из версий. Например, так:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.31.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Вам не нужно заботиться о расположении файла `chromedriver`. Рекомендую вообще удалить следующую строку:

```
// устанавливаем переменную webdriver в system property
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\IGor\\Desktop\\ProjectMaven\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe"); // название и путь
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Добавил в maven. Теперь ошибка выглядит вот так: 

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Может быть еще проблема в самом chromedriver. 
Дело в том, что версия моего браузера 88.0.4324.182

А на скачивание с https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

доступны только 
 89.0.4389.23

 88.0.4324.96

 87.0.4280.88

Я поставил 88.0.4324.96

Comment: @IgorKonel Только что перепроверил - тест проходит. Для теста использовался драйвер из установленого `Chromium` версии `86.0.4240.111`. Немного не понятна новая ошибка, описанная Вами. Добавьте больше информации

Comment: Скачал указанный вами драйвер. Выводит ту же ошибку. Видимо дело не в нем. Но в чем именно - понять не могу. 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
И все тут. А вы распаковываете драйвер? 
Если засунуть zip файл, то ошибка другая

Comment: удалив первые три зависимости в мавене все заработало. А вот почему - не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ, @Alexandr!

Добавил в maven. Теперь ошибка выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть еще проблема в самом chromedriver.
Дело в том, что версия моего браузера 88.0.4324.182

А на скачивание с https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

доступны только
89.0.4389.23

88.0.4324.96

87.0.4280.88

Я поставил 88.0.4324.96